# Database Not Called - .Exe File

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g

I have created a project named 'Test1'. In that i am just filling a datatable, from database.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1 importProgram = new Test1();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable = importProgram.GetAllUOM();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

  public DataTable GetAllUOM()
    {
        DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();
        Console.WriteLine(CommandType.Text);
        Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
        string sql = "SELECT ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION FROM UOM ";
        OracleDataReader dr = OracleHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, CommandType.Text, sql);
            _dataTable.Load(dr);
        Console.WriteLine(_dataTable.Rows.Count);
        return _dataTable;
    }
```

Imported the following

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
```

This is working fine in my local environment. I have build and deployed the exe in server and checking. 
There, after this line "string sql = "SELECT ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION FROM UOM ";" its not running. The command prompt is keep on standing.

I have checked the connection string. That is fine.

Is there anything i need to do, like permission related things etc.?

Comment: You get any exception or error message on your deployment environment? What do you mean by _its not running_?

Comment: In my local environment, its working fine with out any exceptions. But in server, i am trying to get the 'Console.WriteLine(_dataTable.Rows.Count);' row count, which is returning as '0'. But the table is having 15 counts. I dont know, whether the query is executing in server.

Comment: How is your connection string specified? Are you using the TNSNAMES and if yes, is it present at the server?

Comment: The connection string in exe.config will be,
<connectionStrings>
   <add connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXX)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=XXXX;Password=XXX;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" name="OracleConnection"/>
  </connectionStrings>